# return Array Promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

I am trying to return Array of Promise after processed my nested for loop.. Below is the code written to extract certain details from webpage using one of the protractor test framework..

```
this.getFulldetails = function () {
    let nameValues = [];
    return this.getAddressCount().then((values) => {
            for (let m = 0; m < values; m++) {
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css(getLinked(m)))), defaultWait),
                nameValues.push(browser.findElement(by.css(getLinkedAddressCnt(m))).getText());
            for (let i = 0; i < cValues; i += 1) {
                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(locators.nameValue)), defaultWait);
                nameValues.push(browser.findElement(by.css(getLinked(m)))
                    .findElement(by.css(getIndividual(i)))
                    .findElement(locators.nameValue)
                    .getText());
                nameValues.push(browser.findElement(by.css(getLinked(m)))
                    .findElement(by.css(getIndividual(i)))
                    .findElement(locators.periodValue)
                    .getText());
            }
        })
    }
    return Promise.all(nameValues)
    // return nameValues
    });
};
```

When I return just 'return nameValues' then it is returning array[10] elements however when I return Promise.all(nameValues) it is returning empty array []... how can I resolve the promise in the above code.. sorry I am not advanced javascript developer and not used much of promise

Comment: note, your code is deceptively indented, and has errors with unbalanced `()` and `{}`

Comment: I have had checked looks fine and did not throw any error for that.. please explain

Comment: `looks fine` - well, it's not, put it in firefox scratchpad or jsfiddle, hit `pretty print` / `tidy` button - see how code changes, click on the } or ) above the return Promise.all line, see that they are RED, means there's a problem - so, the code you posted here is invalid anyway